# Confusion about dependencies in cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I come from a Java background, and I am using the [hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/) library to build an HTTP proxy. So I added `hyper` and `tokio`  to Cargo.toml. I was following the [http_proxy](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/examples/http_proxy.rs) example, but first I had to add `http` and `futures-util` to Cargo.toml. Otherwise, rustc reported an error.

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module http
```

The `hyper` crate depends on `http`, so it means the dependency in cargo can't be shared to my project?
But I see the `http 0.2.3`in Clion's `External Libraries` list. In a Java project  built by Maven, the dependency can be shared from jar to my project, So I can use it directly.

Comment: I'm not in position to answer right now, but [this](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L73) should be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The hyper crate depends on http, so it means the dependency in cargo can't be shared to my project? But I see the http 0.2.3 in Clion's External Libraries list. In a Java project built by Maven, the dependency can be shared from jar to my project, So I can use it directly.

That's correct. You can only use declared direct dependencies: indirect dependencies can't be assumed to be part of the direct dependency's API, so they could be removed in any minor update, breaking semver guarantees.

However there are cases where the direct dependency will *re-export* part of its own dependency (or even the underlying dependency in its entirety), as "E_net4 with 20k" links that seems to be the case for `hyper` which re-exports parts of `http`. If what Hyper re-exports does not suffice for your use case, then yes you will have to add an explicit dependency on `http` to access what you need beyond that.